# extract iFrame content using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, iframe, beautifulsoup

On the page bellow --> [link](http://pausemusicale.com/electro-pop-voluptueuse-avec-private-life-lost-boy/), I'm trying to use `BeautifulSoup` in order to extract the `<a>` texts at the very bottom, i.e., `'Private Life'` and `'Lost Boy'`.

But I'm having a hard time scraping `<iframe>` content.

I've learned that it requires a different request from the browser.

So I've tried:

```
iframexx = soup.find_all('iframe')
for iframe in iframexx:
    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(iframe)
        results = BeautifulSoup(response)
        print results
```

but that returns `None`.

how do I parse the html bellow so I can fetch each `a['href'].get_text()`?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers will load the iframe content in a separate request, so you'll need to fetch the url that is present in the iframe `src`. You can use selenium if you want, or scrape the data itself directly.
Here is an example:

```
import requests
import re

url = 'https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/310079005&color=ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false'

response = requests.get(url)

Artist = re.search(b'(?<=artist":")(.*?)(?=")', response.content).group(0).decode("utf-8")
Song = re.search(b'(?<=title":")(.*?)(?=")', response.content).group(0).decode("utf-8")

print ("%s - %s" % (Artist, Song))
```

> Private Life - Lost Boy

Comment: How are you fetching the url using python script only?

Comment: @TheMightyNight It looks like Zroq manually put the url from the iframe ```src``` in their ```url``` variable. As in, they didn't fetch it programmatically.