# get PDFs in iframe id="swGoogleDrive"

Tags: python-3.x, iframe, beautifulsoup, lxml

How do I get the PDFs found in the iframe of this [URL](https://www.d88a.org/domain/102)?

[image]

(1) The following code throws an error.

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = r'https://www.d88a.org/domain/102'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'C19SchoolsWebscrape'}

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
iframe_src = soup.select_one("swGoogleDrive").attrs["src"]
r = s.get(f"https:{iframe_src}")
print(r)
```

```
error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'
```

(2) This also throws an error.

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
t = re.search(b'(?<=artist":")(.*?)(?=")', response.content).group(0).decode("utf-8")
print(t)
```

```
error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Earlier threads I've referenced:
[Python BeautifulSoup - Scrape Web Content Inside Iframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54522364/python-beautifulsoup-scrape-web-content-inside-iframes),
[extract iFrame content using BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42589907/extract-iframe-content-using-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all links to the PDFs, you can use this example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.d88a.org/domain/102'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(soup.iframe['src']).content, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.select('a'):
    print(a['href'])
```

Prints:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bCXyoE7FWWI9RIcDWosHrohYQY7Ryb13/view?usp=drive_web
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SlR-71M-jCMF-AO4ChdSbywolIF9yL1h/view?usp=drive_web
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zbrt5Mnt0fZxjeD7DRYvfP6cskYKig27/view?usp=drive_web
```

Comment: Cheers man! I see now my mistake was not making two requests--one for the URL and one for the iframe.

Comment: Could you briefly tell me what the ```href``` represents? I'm trying to understand why when I ```print(len(a['href']))``` I get ```84```? There are currently only 4 PDFs.

Comment: @Pfalbaum `a['href']` will get content of `href="..."` attribute. When you do `len(a['href'])` it will print length of string `"https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bCXyoE7FWWI9RIcDWosHrohYQY7Ryb13/view?usp=drive_web"`, which is 84.

Comment: Oh, I see. How would you print the number of links (PDFs)?

Comment: To answer my own comment, I did this to get the number of links: ```print(len(soup.select('a')))```